# Dropdown Action Menu with Web Link

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, webview

[image: view]

As i tried to show on image, in my app i 've an address bar, dropdown action menu and a webview.

My question is ; how can i add described web links which is when clicked goes to link in webview?
Menu will not be changeable or addable.

Thank you.

Comment: How is your drop-down menu implemented? Is it part of the ActionBar? Is it just a button that you listen for in order to show a PopupWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the source code , I think it help you. Here  `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener Click Event`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** An array of strings to populate dropdown list */
    String[] actions = new String[] {
        "Bookmark",
        "Subscribe",
        "Share"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);

        /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        /** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition]  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        };

        /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
        getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
    }
}
```